# Washington OpenIE 4 - How to pass multiple files as input?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, information-extraction

I'm trying to run the OpenIE tool from [Washington University KnowItAll](https://github.com/knowitall/openie) project, but I need to run it of several hundred files, and it takes the tool around 30s just to start, so I was trying to find a way to start it once and send all the files.

From the documentation, it says that besides the command-line interface, it can take one input file and one output file, by being called like this:

```
sbt 'run-main edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIECli InFile OutFile'
```

My question is if it is possible to send more input files without changing the source code?
Maybe by using the assembled standalone jar, for instance?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I ended just doing an ugly change to the source code. If anyone is interested in it, ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem. I hacked together [a server](https://github.com/yiboyang/openie-server) that wraps the jar, which takes GET requests and serves JSON. Maybe this could help other people.